# Dynamic Height Calculation of UITableViewCell depend upon TextView's height

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I have given the leading and trailing to textview inside content of tableview . I want to dynamically calculate the height of Tableviewcell. the height calculation is working fine sometimes but sometimes not working particular devices like 5c.

i have used following code to estimate the height of text :

```
func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 10000000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.init(name: FontStyle.FontName.kDefault, size: 15.0)!], context: nil)
}
```

The important thing here is the text is HTML text, I have converted it into plain text. then that plain text is passed to above functions.

Comment: What are the component in the UITableViewCell.??

Comment: have you use autolayout?

Comment: yes i have used autolayout

Comment: set tableview cell height to `Automatic Dimension` and set `Leading,Trailing,Top ad Bottom` constraint to textview in cell.Then set scroll enabled to `false`.That's it no need to calculate height on your own `Automatic Dimension` will take care of that

Comment: i already done this bro...Automatic dimension don't work on this case.

Comment: @RahulUmap Can you add your UI Image and your working flow?

Comment: sorry bro . can't add the image due to data policy .

Comment: leading,trailing, top, bottom is set to zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Give top,bottom,leading and trailing to textview inside content of tableview cell.
2. Disable the scrolling of textview. Then and then, this method works. It is generally used in chat cells, wherein we want the property of automatic Data detection of links, phone numbers minus the scrolling of uitextview.
3. Set automatic row height calculation using below methods of table view

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
   {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat

   {
      return 100
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks it worked... but can you please tell me what is 100 in  estimate height

Comment: when content is less ,it set cell size to 100

Answer (score 1):

```
-(CGSize) sizeForStirngInFrameSize:(CGSize)viewSize withFont:(UIFont *)font{
CGSize stringSize = [self boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(viewSize.width, viewSize.height) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil].size;
return stringSize;
}
```

I created this method to find height for my UI label and UITextView, you can use same to calculate height for your textview and return in **heightForRowAt**... delegate method.

Make sure you pass proper viewSize and same Fonts. And constraints.

Thanks

Comment: Ashwin  i used same method for calculation of height. constraints are leading , trailing , top , bottom. all are set to zero.

Comment: HTML text is converted into plain text using following  method

Comment: let attributedString = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                                                                 options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                                                 documentAttributes: nil)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 15.0)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
            return attributedString

Comment: So, is this working or not? as Its working fine for me... FYI, Now a days i'm working in swift and i have imported string category with above method and its working fine in swift as well...

Comment: it works fine for sometimes. i think it may be due to HTML text . which i am converting it into plain text .

Comment: May be, But i think it should not impact as we are calculating size of text which has same font family and size. Anyway let me know once you point out exact cause so I can update my knowledge. :)

Comment: sure , i will let you know .

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension  worked  for me .       tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140

Comment: it had automatically calculated dynamic height

Comment: So will is calculate textview's content size and make it that much bigger in height? For labels it will do as no scroll so enlarge based on text. It seems strange. Anyway thanks for update :)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(textView.contentSize.height)
}
```