# Setting UITableViewCell height programmatically with Auto Layout

Tags: swift, autolayout

I want to set my cell height with auto layout, here is the code:

```
class AccountsBalanceResidueCell : BaseCell {

    private let title: UILabel = {
        let lbl = LabelSL.italicLarge()
        lbl.text = Strings.Common.accountsResidue.value
        return lbl
    }()

    private let amount: UILabel = LabelSL.italicLarge()

    func setup(_ amount: String) {
        self.amount.text = amount + " " + Strings.Common.roubleSymbol.value
    }

    override func prepare() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(title)
        addSubview(amount)
        setConstraints()
    }

    private func setConstraints(){
        let height: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.3333

        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    }
}
```

However, I got an error in the log:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try
>   this:         (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect;         (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint
>   or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active)>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431242/dynamic-height-calculation-of-uitableviewcell-depend-upon-textviews-height/42432679#42432679 check this answer may be it will helps you

Comment: It seems there are two constrains on a single object which is causing ambiguity to compiler.

Try to remove any one of those or try to change constraint's priority.

Answer (score 0):

Did solve this by adding auxiliary view:

```
private let container: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    return view
  }()

container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    let heightConstraint = container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
    heightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 751)
    heightConstraint.isActive = true
```